# Difference between .net TcpClient and Delphi2010 IdTCPClient

Tags: c#, .net, delphi, delphi-2010, tcpclient

I have the following code written in delphi2010:

```
  TCPClient := TidTcpClient.Create;

  TCPClient.Host := '192.168.12.131';
  TCPClient.Port := 1312;

  TCPClient.Connect;

  TCPClient.IOHandler.WriteLn('msg', TEncoding.ASCII);
  answer := TCPClient.IOHandler.ReadLn(TEncoding.ASCII);
```

This code works well - i get answer.

And i have the following C# code:

```
var client = new TcpClient();
client.Connect(endpoint);

var stream = client.GetStream();
var msgData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("msg");
stream.Write(msgData, 0, msgData.Length);

var answerData = new Byte[256];
var asnwerLength = stream.Read(answerData, 0, answerData.Length);
```

And it didn't work - request timeout.

What is difference between these two parts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your delphi code is writing (by the looks of things) a complete line - presumably with some line ending characters. Maybe the server is expecting those?

Try:

```
var client = new TcpClient();
client.Connect(endpoint);

var stream = client.GetStream();
var msgData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("msg\r\n"); //Include line ending. Might just need \r or \n by themselves - consult server documentation, if available
stream.Write(msgData, 0, msgData.Length);

var answerData = new Byte[256];
var asnwerLength = stream.Read(answerData, 0, answerData.Length);
```

Also, you need to bear in mind that `stream.Read` will return as much data as it currently has available - which may be less than a complete message from the server, or may include (parts of) several messages from the server. If you want to duplicate the `ReadLn` behaviour, you'll need to search in the receive buffer for end of line characters yourself.